# Use expl3 variable decimal representation outside of expl3 block

Tags: expl3

Suppose, I have a floating point value inside expl3 block. Can I use it's decimal representation outside of expl3 block?

This doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N  \val
\fp_set:Nn \val{6.5}

\fp_set:Nn \val \fp_to_decimal:N \val
\ExplSyntaxOff
\val
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line

```
\fp_set:Nn \val \fp_to_decimal:N \val
```

is wrong code. If we remove it and ask TeX `\show\val`, we get

```
> \val=macro:
->\s__fp \__fp_chk:w 10{1}{6500}{0000}{0000}{0000};.
```

which tells us that `\val` cannot probably be used by itself in a document, because in some sense it contains an abstract representation of the floating point variable. You have to say

```
\fp_use:N \val
```

in order to deliver in the input stream the representation of the floating point value. Saying `\fp_to_decimal:N \val` is the same, as explained in the documentation.

There is no official document interface for floating point variables, at the moment, so you have to define your own. For instance

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfpvar}{m}{\fp_new:N #1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}{\fp_set:Nn #1 { #2 }}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getfpvar}{m}{\fp_use:N #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

so you can say

```
\newfpvar{\val}
\setfpvar{\val}{6.5+3.01} % any floating point expression
\getfpvar{\val}
```

Don't forget to add `\usepackage{xparse}` to your preamble.